USB Pen drive malfunction?
Have a USB pen drive which has been loaded with photos for displaying on our Android TV
Worked fine showing the photos first time round. Went to add some more photos from our Ubuntu 22.04LTS and the pen drive stopped working. Removed from computer, re-inserted to the computer and was asked to Mount it. Clicked 'Yes' and now the drive only results in the message to mount it. It has once shown on the system manager as 'sdf without being given that name.
Is this a USB hub problem or something more profound.
I also have printer, wired mouse,speaker and camera on this same computer. 2 newly acquired HDD drives work fine through a USB hub on my pci card.
I am reluctant to force any more work on pen drives as a new pen drive has now suffered the same fate on the same connection as the photo drive.
Any ideas?

This question is similar to: How to fix USB pendrive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Search for other answers on this site and in the forums like https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2485643.  The little fingernail sized USB storage may overheat on a big data transfer, but internally there might be a working micro-sd card (after all else fails (ddrescue?) trying to read the USB, pull it apart to see what's inside).
